# Pass multiple values through onClick into one variable or array

Tags: javascript, variables, onclick

so I've tried this very hard but can't figure it out,

I have a button like this

```
<button onclick="signUp(document.getElementById('username').value,document.getElementById('email').value)">Sign up</button>
```

and I want to pass the values it's requesting from some inputs into a variable or variable array so I can handle them like this (example)

```
var signUp = function(e){
    alert(e);
}
```

(This is just simplified but it proves my point!)
Does anyone know how to do this though, I've been having a hard time figuring it out!

Thanks in advance, Magn0053

Comment: Just add an another argument `var signUp = function(e, f) {...`

Comment: Yes but I would like to use them all in the "e", like some sort of array

Comment: Then you have to pass just an array `signUp([val1, val2])`

Comment: Or access `arguments`, but you're really complicating it, just use two arguments instead.

Comment: Rather than passing the values to the function, you can also get it in your function itself - I do not understand the reason of passing value of some elements in function?

Comment: Would I then be able to use them one by one in a "tester" if they're empty?

Comment: @nikhil, cuz I want to use them in another function as well, where it'll be even more tricky the way you describe

Comment: @MagnusVestergaard - So form that object/array in the signUp function and then pass it to other functions.

Comment: I found a solution, thx to @adeneo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may take @adeneo's idea or, just send'em in an array like this

```
signUp([document.getElementById('username').value, 
    document.getElementById('email').value])
```

Comment: This is really bad practice. Say you want to use the signup on another page - now you have to include all this html again rather than just include the same js file. What's more, in an array you have no idea what each element is.

Comment: what html are you talking about?

Answer (score 2):

You can surround by { } to pass them as an object, or [ ] to pass them as an array. However, all of your arguments are document values, your function could just reference them itself.

Answer (score 0):

## Basic Solution

The most basic modification is to use `[]` around the values you are passing to `signUp`.

```js
var signUp = function(e) {
  alert ("username:" + e[0]);
  alert ("email:" + e[1]);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="username">
<input type="text" id="email">
<button onclick="signUp([document.getElementById('username').value,document.getElementById('email').value])" id="submit">Sign up</button>
```

## Best Practice

You don't really want to be using javascript in your DOM so first modify your `signUp` function:

```
signUp = function() {
    var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
}
```

Finally, remove the onclick from your HTML entirely and replace it with this javascript:

```
document.getElementById('submit').onclick=signUp;
```

```js
var signUp = function() {
  var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
  var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
  alert("username:" + username);
  alert("email:" + email);
}

document.getElementById('submit').onclick = signUp;
console.log("fred");
```

```html
<input type="text" id="username">
<input type="text" id="email">
<button id="submit">Sign up</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this as such:

```
<button onclick="signUp({username:document.getElementById('username').value,email:document.getElementById('email').value})">Sign up</button>
```

In js, you can access them like:

```
var signUp = function(e){
    console.log(e.username, e.email);
}
```

Comment: Why would you send an array of objects? Just send an object: `{username: document.blahblah, email: document.blahblah}`